# docker swarm throws 404 page not found error while checking node details

Tags: linux, docker, docker-swarm

I'm setting up a swarm cluster. I am able to see the details with `docker -H :4000 info`. However when i try `docker -H :4000 node ls` it fails.

OS - RHEL 7

**docker version**:

```
$ docker version
Client:  
 Version:      1.12.3  
 API version:  1.24  
 Go version:   go1.6.3  
 Git commit:   6b644ec  
 Built:  
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64  

Server:  
 Version:      1.12.3  
 API version:  1.24  
 Go version:   go1.6.3  
 Git commit:   6b644ec  
 Built:  
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

**docker info**:

```
$ docker -H :4000 info
Containers: 23  
 Running: 23  
 Paused: 0  
 Stopped: 0  
Images: 35  
Server Version: swarm/1.2.5  
Role: primary  
Strategy: spread  
Filters: health, port, containerslots, dependency, affinity, constraint  
Nodes: 7  
...  
...  
Plugins:  
Volume:  
Network:  
Swarm:  
NodeID:  
Is Manager: false  
Node Address:  
Security Options:  
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64  
Operating System: linux  
Architecture: amd64  
CPUs: 28  
Total Memory: 114 GiB  
Name: c7ef56122f88  
Docker Root Dir:  
Debug Mode (client): false  
Debug Mode (server): false
```

**docker node ls**:

```
docker -H :4000 node ls
*Error response from daemon: 404 page not found*
```

**http-proxy.conf**:

```
[Service]
[Service] Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy-domain.com:port" "HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy-domain.com:port"
```

**docker.conf**:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -g /docker --cluster-store=consul://0.0.0.0:8500 --cluster-advertise eth0:2375
```

Not sure what I am missing here. My goal here is to apply swarm node label metadata so that I can make different pools as their sizes.
Any help would be appreciated.

> **PS**: I am able run `docker -H 4000 pull`/`start`/`stop`/`rmi`/`rm`/`network` commands without any issue. its the "node" command does not work with swarm cluster.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using docker swarm with service discovery(consul). docker swarm node management is available on new docker swarm mode(natively supported by docker engine 1.12+ - https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/). I will update the infrastructure to new swarm mode and will provide my findings here.